# Can chat be enhanced by tagging?

Tags: feature-request, tags, chat

I would like to enhance chat by being able to add tags to messages. So in addition to text and fkey being submitted, we can have a set of tags defined by room owners which we can then used to filter messages. We have our own chat client so don't need to wait for a browser client improvement.  It's a logical extension of tagging questions to tagging discussion.

Comment: You could use `[tag:reviewpls] your message` and then search for `reviewpls`.

Comment: embed inside the message? Too obtrusive.  It's meta data.

Answer (score 10):

No.

If you find yourself needing to categorise your conversations so as to set them apart from other conversations, then you should be having them in a separate chat room, dedicated to those kinds of conversations.

In short: *this already exists*.